# CSS "Background-image" doesn't display

Tags: html, css, image, background, display

I'm new to HTML and CSS and I encounter a problem that I just can't figure out. It has happened before in other attempts but in this case I was trying out bootstrap. So I don't think that there's the problem (in every case, my style.css file crushes the css files used for bootstrap).
So here are the facts. I want to create a logo that, when hovered, changes appearance. My css file is linked because the background colors does appear. The hover option works fine too. I must have forgotten something or lack some knowledge.
This question is frequently asked but I haven't found any answer able to help me.

[image: screenprint of the code], in case you want to check it out yourself and my files

```css
.mclogo {
 width: 45px;
 height: 45px;
 background-image: url('./pic/LogoMc1.png');
 background-color: red;
}

.mclogo:hover {
 background-color: blue;
 background-image: url('./pic/LogoMc2.png');
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/style.css">

    <title>Server :: le rôle-play sur minecraft</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 <!--- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://minecraft.net/en-us/"><div class="mclogo"></div></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>   
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
   <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Accueil</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Où suis-je ?</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Le serveur</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nous rejoindre</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>





    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try to remove the code from css file and to add it in the html file <style type="text/css">.mclogo {
 width: 45px;
 height: 45px;
 background-image: url('./pic/LogoMc1.png');
 background-color: red;
}
</style>

Answer (score 0):

try removing the "." out of your file path on your css. In order for relative paths to work on CSS and HTML, you need to make sure it follows standard file notation

Comment: It seems like getting rid of the "." doesn't help. I've tried putting the images in the same file as the index.html and just putting the name of the image between ' ' but it doesn't work aswell.
I'll get rid of the futur dots for sure for the sake of standard file notation.
Thx for the fast reaction tho ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you view your image in the browser at the address you are specifying? In other words, does typing www.yourwebsite.com/pic/LogoMc1.png into your browser's address bar bring up the image?

If not the path is wrong.

If your browser does find the image at that address, try using the absolute path in your CSS declaration. If that doesn't work, you must be overriding these declarations somewhere later in your CSS file.